# DML statement found null SObject at position 0

Tags: scheduled-apex

Got an error:
DML statement found null SObject at position 0
I wrote scheduler class where i find error.

```
global class update_Account implements Schedulable    
{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) 
    {
    Map<Id,Account>AccountToChangeRequest=new map<Id,Account>([Select id,name,(Select Id,Updated__c,Lead_Merchant_Name__c,New_Value__c,Request_Type__c from Change_Requests__r where Updated__c= False  and Lead_Merchant_Name__c!= NULL order by CreatedDate asc limit 1)from Account]);
    system.debug('--AccountToChangeRequest--->>'+AccountToChangeRequest);
    list<Account>AccountToBeUpdated=new List<Account>();
    system.debug('--AccountToBeUpdated--->>'+AccountToBeUpdated);
    list<Change_Request__c> changerequestToBeUpdated=new List<Change_Request__c>();
    system.debug('--changerequestToBeUpdated--->>'+changerequestToBeUpdated);
    for(Id i:AccountToChangeRequest.keyset()) 
    {
         if(AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r.size()>0)
         {
            Account acc=new Account(id=i);
            Change_Request__c cr;
            if(AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r[0].Request_Type__c=='First Name')
            {
                acc.firstname=AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r[0].New_Value__c;
                system.debug('--acc.firstname--->>'+acc.firstname);
                cr=new Change_Request__c(id=AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r[0].id,Updated__c=true);
                system.debug('--cr--->>'+cr);
            }
            else if(AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r[0].Request_Type__c=='Last Name')
            {
                acc.lastname=AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r[0].New_Value__c;
                system.debug('--acc.lastname--->>'+acc.lastname);
                cr=new Change_Request__c(id=AccountToChangeRequest.get(i).Change_Requests__r[0].id,Updated__c=true);
                system.debug('--cr--->>'+cr);
            }
            AccountToBeUpdated.add(acc);
            changerequestToBeUpdated.add(cr);

        }

    }
            if(!AccountToBeUpdated.isEmpty())
            update AccountToBeUpdated;
            system.debug('--AccountToBeUpdated--->>'+AccountToBeUpdated);
            if( !changerequestToBeUpdated.isEmpty())
            update changerequestToBeUpdated;
            system.debug('---changerequestToBeUpdated-->>'+changerequestToBeUpdated);
    }
}
```

Comment: when do u get this error ?did you check the debug logs for all the values you are printing to system.debug

Comment: are you able to save your class? it seems like you need to remove space  Map<Id,Account> AccountToChangeRequest=

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna:Yes i checked the debug logs, When my scheduler class run then I find error at 41 line(DML statement found null SObject at position 0).

Answer (score 1):

When DML (data modification) is being done you have a null value in the list which is not allowed.

The most likely place this is coming from is when `cr` is left `null` because `Request_Type__c` matches neither 'First Name' or 'Last Name'. The simplest fix would be to move these two lines:

```
AccountToBeUpdated.add(acc);
changerequestToBeUpdated.add(cr);
```

inside the `if` statements (i.e. a copy in each `if`).

**PS**
A better approach would be to only query for the types of changes that the code supports. That would look like this:

```
public class update_Account implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Account[] accounts = new Account[] {};
        Change_Request__c[] crs = new Change_Request__c[] {};
        for (Account a : [
                Select Id, (
                        Select Id, New_Value__c, Request_Type__c
                        from Change_Requests__r
                        where Updated__c = False
                        and Lead_Merchant_Name__c != NULL
                        and Request_Type__c in ('First Name', 'Last Name')
                        order by CreatedDate asc
                        limit 1
                        )
                from Account
                ]) {
            if (a.Change_Requests__r.size() == 1) {
                Change_Request__c cr = a.Change_Requests__r[0];
                if (cr.Request_Type__c == 'First Name') {
                    a.FirstName = cr.New_Value__c;
                } else if (cr.Request_Type__c == 'Last Name') {
                    a.LastName = cr.New_Value__c;
                }
                accounts.add(a);
                crs.add(new Change_Request__c(Id = cr.Id, Updated__c = true));
            }
        }
        update crs;
        update accounts;
    }
}
```

This will hit governor limits when there are a large number of Accounts; using a batchable would avoid that problem. And perhaps better still to base this on a query of `Change_Request__c` and get the Account Id from that object.